# selecting required sql from script using shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a sybase ddl file having ddl's of many tables.. but the issue is along wth ddl there are many other things and unnecessary index creation script and comments. Is there any way to extract only ddl from this file. below is a small sample of file.

```
-------------------------------------------
-- DDL fpr table 'prod.dbo.tbl1'
--------------------------------------------
print '<<<< creating table prod.dbo.tbl1
go
setuser 'dbo'
go

create table tbl1 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))

-------------------------------------------
-- DDL fpr table 'prod.dbo.tbl2'
--------------------------------------------
print '<<<< creating table prod.dbo.tbl1
go
setuser 'dbo'
go

create table tbl2 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))
---------------------------------------------------
```

from this file i want only the create table ddl's. is there any way to achieve it.. the output should only be DDL's like below..

```
create table tbl1 id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2);
create table tbl2 id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2);
```

Comment: in the desired output the parens are missing from around the column lists; are you really looking to remove those parens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- only interested in `create table` commands (ie, not interested in other table related DDL like `create index`, RI/check constraints, default/rule bindings, cache configurations, `grant/revoke`, etc)
- a `create table` block is terminated via blank line (no spaces), `go` (starting in column 1) or comment block (`--` starting in column 1)

Sample input file:

```
$ cat ddl.sql
-------------------------------------------
-- DDL fpr table 'prod.dbo.tbl1'
--------------------------------------------
print '<<<< creating table prod.dbo.tbl1
go
setuser 'dbo'
go

create table tbl1 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))

-------------------------------------------
-- DDL fpr table 'prod.dbo.tbl2'
--------------------------------------------
print '<<<< creating table prod.dbo.tbl1
go
setuser 'dbo'
go

create table tbl2 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))
---------------------------------------------------

create table tbl3 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))
go
---------------------------------------------------
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
/create table/         { printme=1 }     # set our "print" flag when we see "create table"
/^$/ || /^go/ || /^--/ { if (printme)    # if in midst of printing "create table" then 
                            print ";"    # print ending ";" and then
                         printme=0       # clear "print" flag
                       }
printme' ddl.sql                         # if "print" flag is set (ie, "=1") then print current line
```

Or as a one-liner with comments removed:

```
awk '/create table/ {printme=1} /^$/ || /^go/ || /^--/ { if (printme) print ";";printme=0} printme' ddl.sql
```

Running the above against my `ddl.sql` generates:

```
create table tbl1 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))
;
create table tbl2 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))
;
create table tbl3 (id numeric (10,0),
                     etity     CHAR(2))
;
```

**NOTE:** If OP needs the ending `;` on the end of the line it is possible to add a bit more code to the `awk` solution ...

Answer (score -1):

If all unwanted lines start with this characters: --, print, go, setuser, ...

You could do:

`cat DDL.txt  | egrep -v '^--|^print|^go|^setuser'`

Comment: few aprint commands are there and many unwanted comments.. i just want the ddl from create table till end of columns